# Из многомерного массива в одномерный. php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив с (внимание)неизвестным уровнем вложенности, как его преобразовать в одномерный?

К примеру, есть массив:

```
$arrayTest = [
        'country' => [
            'Russian Federation' => [
                'Округа' => [
                    'Краснодарский край',
                    'Чеченская республика',
                    'Республика Дагестан'
                ],
                'Москва', 
                'Воронеж', 
                'Ростов-на-Дону'
            ],
            "United States of America" => [
                'Сиэтл', 
                'Вашингтон', 
                'Филадельфия'
            ],
            "China" => [
                'Шанхай', 
                'Пекин', 
                'Гон'
            ]
        ],

        'union' => [
            'СССР', 
            'Европейский союз'
        ], 

        'status' => 1, 

        'age' => 34
    ];
```

Как преобразовать его в одномерный если учесть то, что уровень вложенности неизвестный, как тут:

```
array(
    Краснодарский край
    Чеченская республика
    Республика Дагестан
    Москва
    Воронеж
    Ростов-на-Дону
    Сиэтл
    Вашингтон
    Филадельфия
    Шанхай
    Пекин
    Гон
    СССР
    Европейский союз
    1
    34
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию **[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php)**, которая рекурсивно применяет пользовательскую функцию к каждому элементу массива

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arrayTest, function ($item, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $item;    
});
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что array_walk_recursive начинает работу из "глубины" массива?

Comment: а что выполняет "use (&$result)" в вашем примере?

Answer (score 2):

1. Цикл по массиву
2. Если элемент не массив - складываем в результат
3. Если элемент массив, делаем пункт 1 и объединениям с результатом.

Лучше всего написать функцию и использовать рекурсию.

Comment: хм. выглядит логичным, но почему-то минус на ответе

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я понял и написал работающую функцию:

```
$resArray = []; 
    function convertToSimpleArray($array){
        global $resArray; 
        if(is_array($array)){
            foreach($array as $below){
                $res = convertToSimpleArray($below); 

            }
        }else{
            $resArray[] = $array; 
        }
        return $resArray; 
    }
```

Comment: Скажите, а как можно заменить global ?

Comment: `как можно заменить global` - примерно так http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61ebdef31f242e863b75edb8f04396bb2a088a25   ..... то есть придется по результату возвращаемом в  `convertToSimpleArray` пробежаться циклом и сложить всё в `$resArray`