# php. общий массив в рекурсии, область видимости(замыкания)

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Есть многомерный массив `$allCategories` с неизвестной вложенностью, нужно из него сделать несколько одномерных массивов по 1 уровню, для этого я написал функцию `convertToSimpleArray`.

Для объединения результата в единый массив используется строчка `global $resArray;`, т.е. при каждом вызове функции из цикла массив `$resArray` должен очищаться, так вот, то что сейчас написано в цикле foreach не работает так как надо, массив `$resArray` не очищается, как это исправить?

```
function convertToSimpleArray($array){
    global $resArray; 
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $below){
            $res = convertToSimpleArray($below); 
        }
    }
    else {
        $resArray[] = $array; 
    }

    return $resArray; 
}


$simpleArraysCategories = []; 
$count = 0; 
foreach($allCategories as $category){
    $resArray = []; 
    $simpleArraysCategories[$count] = convertToSimpleArray($allCategories[$count]);
    $count++;
}
```

P.S. В php я новичок, пришёл из js, там хоть замыкания есть.

Comment: а зачем вам глобальный массив, если на глобальном уровне он вообще не используется никак? Зачем цикл `$category` если используете `$count`

Comment: вы бы привели лучше формат исходного массива, и вид конечных массивов, глядишь вам бы и более удобный способ подсказали.

Comment: и обратите внимание на функцию `array_walk_recursive`, возможно вам и не понадобится городить кучу кода?

Comment: @teran что примечательно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711187/191482 :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да уж действительно :)